# How many people were involved in a project? Based on Revision Control System

Tags: svn, git, mercurial, metrics, bazaar

How do you know how many developers were involved in a project using a Revision Control System? A friend of mine found this way to look up the answer in git log:

```
git log | grep Author: | sort -u | cut –delimiter=” ” -f2 | sort -u | wc -l
```

Is there a straightforward way in git? How about other Revision Control System like Subversion, Bazaar or Mercurial?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### git

The [`shortlog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-shortlog.html) command is very useful.  This summarizes the typical `git-log` output.

```
$ git shortlog -sn
   119  tsaleh
   113  Joe Ferris
    70  Ryan McGeary
    45  Tammer Saleh
    45  Dan Croak
    19  Matt Jankowski
    ...
```

Pass to `wc` to see the number of unique usernames:

```
$ git shortlog -sn | wc -l
      40
```

Answer (score 9):

For mercurial, there's an extension to do exactly that: [`hg churn`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ChurnExtension).

`hg churn` sorts by line-changed, if you want changeset count, use `hg churn -c`.

Answer (score 4):

For subversion

```
svn log -q svn://path/to/repo | cut -f 3 -d " "  | sort -u
```

Answer (score 2):

There is stats plugin for Bazaar to get different info about project contributors:

https://launchpad.net/bzr-stats/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a straightforward way for Mercurial either and a good search of all its documentation didn't revealed anything too. So, here's a *nix command, similar to the one your friend found, for Mercurial:

```
hg log | grep user: | cut -c 14- | sort -u | uniq | wc -l
```

BTW, I think there's an error with the command for git, the second `sort -u` should surely be replaced by uniq!

Comment: @Charles Bailey: Look again, it's done two times!

@tonfa: Didn't knew about that one, should look at extensions more closely.

Comment: I agree, the first `sort -u` is redundant in the question, but still, I don't see anything wrong with it. But you also pipe the output of `sort -u` to `uniq` so I was wondering what you made you not trust `sort -u`?

Comment: Oh! My fault didn't knew about the -u option!

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial has a powerful template language built-in (see `hg help templates`). So you can get a list of all people in the project without enabling the churn extension:

```
hg log --template '{author}\n' | sort -u
```

If people have changed their email address (but otherwise kept their name the same), then you can process the `author` template keyword a bit:

```
hg log --template '{author|person}\n' | sort -u
```

Then add `wc -l` as appropriate to the above commands.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler git version is:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:%an | sort -u | wc -l
```

or if you care about unique email addresses:

```
git log --pretty=tformat:%ae | sort -u | wc -l
```